# getStateByPartialCompositeKey is retuning me object which is non iterable

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, composite-primary-key, smartcontracts, ibm-blockchain

A sample code 
let

```
keyIter = ctx.stub.getStateByPartialCompositeKey(this.name, strkey);
console.log("keyIter"+ keyIter);
```

I created composite keys via 2 keys and I am able to see the record in Couch DB. However while trying to get the entire list of all keys which matches the first key I do not get an iterable as per documentation. Pls share the results.

I am using VSE extension and working on IBM Blockchain Platform V0.3.0

Logs

```
keyIter[object Promise]
2019-02-28T23:22:22.132Z ERROR [contracts-spi/chaincodefromcontract.js]  
    {"message":"keyIter is not iterable","stack":"TypeError: keyIter is not iterable\n    at MyContract.query (/usr/local/src/lib/my-contract.js:42:25)\n    at ChaincodeFromContract.invokeFunctionality (/usr/local/src/node_modules/fabric-shim/lib/contract-spi/chaincodefromcontract.js:322:58)\n    at <anonymous>\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)"}
2019-02-28T23:22:22.134Z ERROR [lib/handler.js] [mychannel-6323acf1]Calling chaincode Invoke() returned error response [TypeError: keyIter is not iterable]. Sending ERROR message back to peer
```

Comment: What is the value and type of 'strkey' - I think it should be an array of string.  Have you tested by passing just an empty array? e.g. keyIter = ctx.stub.getStateByPartialCompositeKey(this.name, []);

Comment: Hi , I tried the same but same error . Let me share the code and logs.async query(ctx, key) {
   console.log("key"+ key);
  
   console.info('querying for key: ' + key  );
   var strkey = [key];
   console.log("strkey"+ strkey);
   console.log("this.name::"+ this.name,);
    let keyIter = await ctx.stub.getStateByPartialCompositeKey(this.name, []);
    console.log("keyIter"+ keyIter);
  
    
   for (const numkey of keyIter) {
    console.log("numkey::"+numkey);
   }}

Comment: Logskey12
querying for key: 12
strkey12
this.name::MyContract
keyIter[object Object]
2019-03-01T14:24:14.602Z ERROR [contracts-spi/chaincodefromcontract.js]  
 {"message":"keyIter is not iterable","stack":"TypeError: keyIter is not iterable\n    at MyContract.query (/usr/local/src/lib/my-contract.js:42:25)\n    at <anonymous>\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)"}
2019-03-01T14:24:14.602Z ERROR [lib/handler.js] [mychannel-42373355]Calling chaincode Invoke() returned error response [TypeError: keyIter is not iterable]. Sending ERROR message back to peer

Comment: This working fine after changing the iterator query code. while (true) {
       const res = await keyIter.next();
       console.log("res.value:: "+ res.value);

Answer (score 0):

PLease verify that this.name is the index name and it should be within double quotes . strkey refers to the composite key .